# How can I execute a cat command in a execlp in C?

Tags: linux, c, exec

I'm trying to execute  commands that are passed from the terminal to argv seperated by `:` to be more specific   `cat nevermind : grep left : wc -c`.

`tabCommand` is an array that contains each command so `cat nevermind`,`grep left`,`wc -c`

With printf I can confirm that `tabCommand[i-1]` is indead equal to `cat nevermind` but the output I get is `Error: No such file or directory`

```
 if (execl(tabCommande[i-1],tabCommande[i-1], (char *)NULL) == -1) {
        error_and_exit();
 }
```

If someone can help me find the issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This seems to be more a C question than one about Unix&Linux. I have voted for moving it to SO.

Comment: I'm new to this platform how to a move it ?

Comment: The first parameter to `execl` is the name of the executable, not a command to parse. You're trying to execute a command named "`cat nevermind`", when you really want to `execl` `cat` with a first argument of "`nevermind`".

Comment: if I hardcode ` execl("cat","nevermind", (char *)NULL)` I still get the same error do you know what would be the correct syntax? Or with execlp

Comment: Use the full path to `cat`, which you can find with `type -p cat`.

Comment: And  `cat nevermind | grep left | wc -c` is equivalent to `grep left < nevermind | wc -c` except when `cat` is *not* [cat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comments I got in my post I managed to find my problem

`execlp("/bin/sh","sh","-c",tabCommande[i], (char *)NULL)` works because I need to use the full path.
If I do `execlp(tabCommande[i],tabCommande[i], (char *)NULL)` it won't work because im not using the full path of each command so simply giving `cat` to execlp won't work.

found this answer thanks to **waltinator** I'm new to stack so i dont know how to give you the credit